# How to connect with socket server?

Tags: android, laravel, sockets, server, connection

I have an android studio project. Also I have Laravel server with apache, which listens to port 80 and a socket server which listens to port 6001. When android project wants to authenticate, it sends request to port 80, but I want to keep connection with socket server, to receive some events. How can it be organized?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide between which protocol you want to use, either TCP or UDP. I will talk about connecting with TCP since that is probably what you will want to use. With TCP, if you want to keep connection to the socket server, there is actually no way for you to tell if the connection has dropped. So you will want to utilize a sort of heartbeat where you ping (send some small data) the socket server and wait for the reply. If it replies, then the connection is sound and if it times out then you know that you need to reconnect. Other than that, just send whatever data you want between the socket client and the socket server (I use JSON).